# Python to search email body in outlook by specific word and save as pdf in sharepoint or shared drive

Tags: python, outlook, com-automation

Am new to Python and wanted to try to automate a manual process.

Iterate through outlook folders and search by key word  "Approved" or "Approve" or "approved" or "approve" in the email body. When found, convert to pdf and then save the pdf in a shared drive or SharePoint folder which is uniquely named.

If email has attachments, then save the attachments as well. Is this possible to program in Python?

We have Outlook 2013 but I learned that Outlook 365 has some features. VBA in outlook is grayed out. Any help is much appreciated!

Best Regards,
APA

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am still exploring tools to use to serve my specific needs. After some research, found out Alteryx is ruled out. That leaves Python, which is new to me and then Exceptor which requires little to no coding from what I hear. Thanks for your response, much appreciated!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You can automate Outlook from python. See [Automating Outlook using Python win32com](https://github.com/Hridai/Automating_Outlook#automating-outlook-using-python-win32com) to get started quickly.

> Iterate through outlook folders and search by key word "Approved" or "Approve" or "approved" or "approve" in the email body.

There is no need to iterate through Outlook folders. Instead, you may consider using the `AdvancedSearch` method of the `Application` class.

The key benefits of using the `AdvancedSearch` method in Outlook are:

- The search is performed in another thread. You don’t need to run another thread manually since the `AdvancedSearch` method runs it automatically in the background.
- Possibility to search for any item types: mail, appointment, calendar, notes etc. in any location, i.e. beyond the scope of a certain folder. The `Restrict` and `Find`/`FindNext` methods can be applied to a particular `Items` collection (see the `Items` property of the `Folder` class in Outlook).
- Full support for DASL queries (custom properties can be used for searching too). You can read more about this in the [Filtering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208216%28v=office.12%29) article in MSDN. To improve the search performance, `Instant Search` keywords can be used if Instant Search is enabled for the store (see the `IsInstantSearchEnabled` property of the `Store` class).
- You can stop the search process at any moment using the `Stop` method of the `Search` class.

Read more about the `AdvancedSearch` method in the [Advanced search in Outlook programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/05/31/outlook-search-csharp-vbnet/) article.

You can use the Word editor to save the item using the PDF file format:

```
Word.Document doc = mailItem.GetInspector.WordEditor;
doc.SaveAs2(fullPath, FileFormat: Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF);
```

Also you may consider using the [ExportAsFixedFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.exportasfixedformat) method from the Word object model which saves a document as PDF or XPS format.

The [Attachment.SaveAsFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachment.saveasfile) method saves the attachment to the specified path.

Comment: This code serves my purpose but am new to Python, so would need to learn in order to understand the code syntax and the flow. Thanks a bunch for sharing, much appreciated!